# Where to get Explorerframe.lib from?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I need this library to access the new Windows 7 taskbar functions. However it doesn't seem to be installed with the Microsoft SDKs I have. Does anybody know where I can get this library?

Comment: You could try to convert the explorerframe.dll to a .lib . Just use the internet to search for "DLL to LIB" and it should give you a list of toys.

Comment: You do not need Explorerframe.lib to access the new taskbar functions. The new taskbar functions are available via COM. You access them [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42345/Windows-7-Goodies-in-C-Taskbar-Progress-and-Status).

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes I'm actually following this article to implement the taskbar functions and they make use of the ITaskbarList3 interface, and this interface requires Explorerframe.lib - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The CLSID should be in uuid.lib. The MSDN box is just saying that explorerframe.dll implements the interface, but you shouldn't care. Just let COM find it.

Comment: @RaymondChen, you're right, that was it. I had some error that I thought was due to this missing library but in fact it was something else. And indeed the library is not needed. Thanks a lot. Feel free to put your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Explorerframe.lib is not necessary to use the taskbar functions. As Raymond Chen mentioned in the comments, these functions are available via COM.

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Ahsan, please have a look at the comments below the question for more details. There's also a link with a tutorial on how to use the functions.

Comment: I keep getting this error while compiling : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct ITaskbarList3 * SomeView::p_pTaskBarlist"  I have mostly followed: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80082/Windows-How-to-display-progress-bar-on-taskbar-i?msg=4095455#xx4095455xx

Comment: @Ahsan, I forgot how I got it to work, but if that can be of any help it was for this project: https://github.com/laurent22/fastcopy Maybe check the first few commits, where I got ITaskbarList3 to work.